# VS 2013 will not array size allocation with user inputs

Tags: arrays, constants, visual-studio-2013

I've seen similar questions asked a few times but I'm not able to debug this issue.  I've run into this several times since moving to VS on Win8.1 coming from Dev C++.  When I declare an array size I continue to get the C2057 and C2466 errors during compile time.  I understand that this is related to not having a declared constant at compile time but I'm not sure how to correct the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!  You will see my various attempts but seems to create more errors regardless of which direction I go.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int row, col, r, c;
//const int row = 1;
//const int col = 1;
float k;
cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns you want in your array: " << endl;
cin >> row >> col;
//const int a = row;
//const int b = col;
//float* array = new float[row][col];
float array[row][col];
//vector<float>array[row][col];
cout << "Enter the elements: " << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of dynamic sizes like you try to declare in that code are only part of the C99 standard, not of the older C or the C++ standards. That's why the VS compiler does complain. Because the visual studio compiler still doesn't fully implement the C99 feature set.

To make the code work you will have to use heap allocated memory or even better in C++ use a std::vector.

The syntax you used above for the std::vector is wrong. You rather need something like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector< float > > float_vector(rows, std::vector< float >(cols) );
```

This creates a vector of a vector of floats. The constructor creates `rows` elements in the outer vector, and for each element (i.e. each contained vector) a vector with `cols` elements is used.